# How to pass data from activity to fragment in android using menu button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have these activities:

1. LoginActivity
2. MainActivity
3. ProfileActivity

MainActivity contains 4 fragments: PersonalFragment, PasswordFragment, SettingsFragment, and FacilityFragment.

In PersonalFragment, there are 4 button menus, which one of them is directed to ProfileActivity.

ProfileActivity contains 3 fragments: ProfileDetailFragment, FamilyFragment, and EducationFragment.

Here's the process of my apps:

when I started a LoginActivity and successfully logged in, the server sent me token to access data from web service. I already got the token. Then, I want to get all the data that I want to fetch from API and display it in ProfileDetailFragment. The process needs me to click on PersonalFragment in MainActivity then it will open the ProfileActivity which will display ProfileDetailFragment at first.

What I've tried:

1. Pass the token from LoginActivity to MainActivity and display it with Toast.makeText. This one succeeds
2. Pass the token result that I stored in a new variable in MainActivity like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("token", token);
ProfileDetailFragment fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in ProfileDetailFragment:

```
String strtext = getArguments().getString("token");
```

But still, return null.

3. I also tried to pass it step by step like from LoginActivity,  to MainActivity, PersonalFragment, ProfileActivity, and last is ProfileDetailFragment.

Is there any solution for me :(. FYI: I've read the previous questions and the documentation, but still returns null. Thank You

Comment: if your token needs in all screen then I will suggest store it in sharedprefrence after login success

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan okay, I'll try it, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully login in app, at that time just store your token in `SharedPreference` and you can use same token in all screen, so no need to pass in `Intent`. Please remember to clear preference before you logout form app.

Answer (score 0):

- For things that you want to store in cache, retrieve easily and for most of your screens you can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)
- For one time passing of data between activities, I recommend you use [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)
- For fragments needing data from another source you can use [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle)